# Keep track of added functions for each version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

For my application I want to keep track in which version each function is implemented. Now I just put some text in de comments just like my example:

```
// Checks if a user exists
// Implemented: v2.6.8
public bool CheckIfUserExists(...)
{
    ...
}
```

I do this for every function in my application to see when this was implemented. But is there an easy way or any standard way to see this in some kind of list so I don't have to dive into the code to that specific function to see at which version this was implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the standard way is to use a source control system (such as TFS or GIT) which will be tracking the changes for you.

Comment: With TFS I think you mean Team Foundation Server? Ok I will take a dive into those systems

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by looking in to some version control system e.g. Git.
Check out github.com or bitbucket.org for some online hosted services.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do version control, then use git or TFS as suggested already.

That said, you can use [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) comments and a tool called [SandCastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) to generate a set of help files and/or web pages to help with publishing information that is written next to the code.

Here is a [tutorial](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/09/build-html-documentation-for-y.html) for using Sandcastle

XML comments in C# look like this:

```
/// <summary>
////Checks if a user exists
/// Implemented: v2.6.8
///</summary>
///<returns>
///True if the user exists, false otherwise
///</returns>
public bool CheckIfUserExists(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is also something I was looking for! I think i will combine TFS to keep track of my versions and use Sandcastle for some help files.